# Google Cloud Storage - Knowing who uploaded

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm currently porting a webservice I've built to work with Google App Engine. One of the main functions in the webservice is to upload an image (a profile picture, for example). Currently what I do is:

- Authenticate the user who wants to upload the image using his unique API KEY and other data.
- Upload the file, give it a unique name and store the name of the file inside the user's row in the mysql database.

Now in order to port the file upload to App Engine I'm using Google Cloud Storage and following this tutorial:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload

I'm trying to get the file upload to work with my Android app the following way:

- The user makes a request, the webservice authenticates him and sends in response the upload url created by `CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl`.
- The user uploads the image to this URL
- **Now heres the problem:** After the upload is done, a POST is made to the given php file in `createUploadUrl` (I quote from google's docs) with the uploaded file. But how can this script know who uploaded the file it got? I can't pass any parameters indicating who uploaded the file to createUploadUrl so I can't insert the file name to a user in the Cloud SQL database, so now theres only a file not associated with anything in Cloud Storage.

Any hints? Am I missing something?

Comment: While not ideal, you can submit the API key as additional fields with your POST request. These fields will be forwarded to the URL specified in `createUploadUrl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this as a separate answer because a) it's different approach than the first answer, and b) **I'd advocate for my other answer over this one** because I think it's best to let GAE handle auth.  However, I think you can do what you're trying to do this way:

Instead of routing a singular URL to your upload handler, use a regex match like this in your app.yaml to route any matching URLs to your handler:

```
 handlers:
 - url: upload_handler/(.*)
   script: my-php-script-that-uploads-stuff.php
```

Then when invoking `createUploadURL`, simply pass in your API_KEY after the `'upload_handler/'` as a query argument, e.g.

```
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl(sprintf('/upload_handler/?API_KEY=%s', $API_KEY), $options);
```

Then in `my-php-script-that-uploads-stuff.php`:

```
parse_str(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['query'])
```

This will parse the request URL to get the query string and then parse the query string, populating the value of API_KEY with the value passed in the URL in your local scope.

I just tested this pattern of extracting stuff from the request URL in a php script in with dev_appserver and it worked.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I've been looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by using the [google appengine users service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/users/) in your php script.

From the link above, from the Overview page of the users service, here's how you get the current user:

```
use google\appengine\api\users\User;
use google\appengine\api\users\UserService;

$user = UserService::getCurrentUser();
```

Comment: The problem is, this is a webservice for mobile devices so I can't really see who's logged in since they're not (UserService should display a login screen but they can't see it). Also, not all of my users have google accounts.

Comment: @Eran what is the authentication you refer to in the first step for the upload url?

Comment: Each user has a unique API key which is assigned to him when he registers / logins. Each request he sends has the API key in it to verify the request is valid and know it's origin.

Comment: @Eran Is there a reason you don't want to use the [OpenID auth made available by GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/openid)?  One of the nice features of GAE is that it can handle doing things like auth and user identification for you, allowing you to drop your own auth mechanisms and simplify your code and reduce your exposure to bugs and exploitation.  I'd imagine most people, even if not google account-holders, would have OpenID valid accounts.

Comment: @akgill I'm aware of the OpenID auth GAE allows but was unable to understand how can it be made available to android users, for example.